# regex non-capturing group

Tags: python, regex

I have an assignment that is to have 4 groups. First group is a number, second group is number, third group is number and last group is either pm or am (am|pm)

However if I write this:

```
^([1-9]|[1-2][0-2]?)(:[1-5][0-9]|0[1-9])?(:[1-5][0-9]|0[1-9])?(am|pm)$
```

It is gonna return (:number) for group 2 and 3, and I want to put ":" in a non-capturing group, so I changed it slightly to the following code:

```
^([1-9]|[1-2][0-2]?)(?::)?([1-5][0-9]|0[1-9])?(?::)?([1-5][0-9]|0[1-9])?(am|pm)$
```

However, 6::pm is evaluated to be legal expression. How can I make this expression work when string ":" is prompted, a number has to be prompted, at the same time it doesn't capture ":" inside a group with my number?
Return statement should be:

```
(number, number, number, am or pm) instead of (number, :number, :number, am or pm)
```

Edit:

```
pattern = ^([1-9]|[1-2][0-2]?)(?::)?([1-5][0-9]|0[1-9])?(?::)?([1-5][0-9]|0[1-9])?(am|pm)$
Input = "6:30am"
x = re.match(pattern, Input)
print(x.groups())

>>> (6,30,none,am)
```

":" will be ignored when print out

Comment: Having trouble understanding, can you please post example input and expected output?

Comment: @JustinFuruness edited

Comment: You just had one `:` to match, why your re have 2 `:`?

Comment: @atline the seconds i guess, ie 06:30:14am. If not needed indeed the second : is useless

Comment: @AlexHu You had to give all expected clearly instead let guys to guess...

Comment: @atline sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need absolutely the four groups, remove the `?` quantifiers:

```
^([1-9]|[1-2][0-2]?):([1-5][0-9]|0[1-9]):([1-5][0-9]|0[1-9])(am|pm)$
```

https://regex101.com/r/R2m8VR/1

Edit: if you don't need the seconds, the following one is enough:

```
^([1-9]|[1-2][0-2]?):([1-5][0-9]|0[1-9])(am|pm)$
```

https://regex101.com/r/plvz3V/1

Edit: if the `:` is optional, put it in a non capturing group with a `?` quantifier, so the group with the `:` and the last two digits will become optional:

```
^([1-9]|[1-2][0-2]?)(?::([1-5][0-9]|0[1-9]))?(am|pm)$
```

https://regex101.com/r/plvz3V/2

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but ":" is optional. In other words, 6am should be legal in this case